# Download direct image links in Excel 2003

Tags: download, macros, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a list of about 6,000 direct links to images in an excel sheet, and I need to download them all automatically onto my computer into a directory keeping the same file names. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- put them in a txt file
- download [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) to that directory where you want them
- `wget -i my_links.txt`

If it doesn't work, give here the error.

Comment: I receive an error in the command prompt. 

'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you do the second step above - you'll have to get wget.exe out of the zip you downloaded.

Comment: Complete package, except sources?

Comment: Okay. Figured that out. Now I'm getting something else. "Invalid URL : Unsupported scheme"

Comment: @NathanielHirschler - For you to be able to start wget from any directory, you would have to put it into a PATH env. variable. Since you need wget for this one time only, I thought it would be easier to skip that path, therefore putting wget directly into the target directory. Forget the link I gave. Here is another http://quadlasers.com/wp/?p=423 ... download the .rar package (click on the white "thing") and open it. You will get lots of files from the archive, but you need only wget.exe ... after you have it proceed as desribed.